# Log4net Output: Help to figure out what is wrong

Tags: log4net

My config seems fine to me... i have this in assembly info:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", 
                                          Watch = true)]
```

Yet i see no log files being created...I know the config is fine cos i copied it from another project that logs just fine...

I enabled Internal debugging and got the below in output, please see if you can help me make sense of it:

```
     log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]. 
 Loaded from [C:\Users\ojohnson\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root \ce2cc35f\341d86e7\assembly\dl3\9a453d91\9a9af63d_14ecce01\log4net.dll]. (.NET Runtime  [4.0.30319.17929] on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [Dynamic Assembly]
 log4net: Assembly [Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type     [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [Remita.STPService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
 log4net: Assembly [Remita.STPService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\Users\ojohnson\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ce2cc35f\341d86e7\assembly\dl3\f305a8f8\46d161c4_da86cf01\Remita.STPService.dll]
 log4net: Assembly [Remita.STPService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
 log4net: Assembly [Remita.STPService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
 log4net: repository [log4net-default-repository] already exists, using repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
```

What repository is it talking about?

Comment: The [default repository](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository.html), as you haven't specified a [custom repository](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.RepositoryAttribute.html). As log4net is being configured but not creating a file I think @peer is probably right and it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied the config from an other project, check if your user has access to the logging directory. Next change the name of the logging file. If the other project is logging to the same file, it could be locked. You can log from 2 places to one file when setting Minimal locking in the file appender.